# Renaming an image based off of a variable?

Tags: php, html

I am using the following code from W3Schools, which you can find [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp).
However, I have heard that this is not the safest way to upload images, and it doesn't meet what I need to do. What I need is while the file is uploading, it is renamed based off of a variable, $data['id'], which would be implemented like so:

```
<img src="banners/<?php echo $data['id']?>.jpg; ?>">
```

Additionally, if someone uploaded another banner and it was renamed based off of the $data['id'], the old banner would be overwritten with the new one.
If you could lead me in the direction to a wiki, or help me make the script here, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As an added suggestion, you really should find better sources for code tutorials than W3Schools.  THere examples as often woefully incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From W3School

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

should be replaced with

```
$filename  = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$new       = $data['id'].'.'.$extension;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $new);
```

to change the filename.

Answer (score 0):

There are many answers on SO, just look for "secure file upload".
To my mind the main idea is to use a framework and not to roll out your own functions. Php - Silex, Laravel, Symfony, pick one and use all the batteries included.
Have fun !